# C# Form Region - Capture the Outlook 2013 Send event

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm working on an application that should capture the Outlook 2013 Send event.
I'm adding a new Adjoining Outlook Form Region to Appointment, I want save some data in my database when  someone hit the SEND button.
I appreciate any help

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the MailItem.Send or Application.ItemSend events:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076%28v=office.15%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865379%28v=office.15%29.aspx